# Navigating through <td> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, append

Created the fiddle with the sample code here @ http://jsfiddle.net/DgPv6/2/

I have a table with 2 `<td>`s, In the first I have titles and in the second I have corresponding items related, first always shows up but the second will show only the content that you are on, for example Country will show list of countries and when you click on language it will show list of countries.

1. Here list of countries is checkboxes and languages is radio buttons.
2. The issue:

I am trying to add an image to the corresponding title only if any of the items from the second are in a selected state be it a radio or a checkbox using jquery.

I have tried selecting any input checkboxes checked but that did not work. Any suggestions here, how to parse between two tds here?

```
$("input:checked").each(function() {
             $("div.lnk").append("<img class='tick'></img>");

            });
```

Comment: I think you need an event handler: `$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {...})` -- http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: inside the event handler - not sure how to navigate between the tds here, like if any of the checkboxes checked then add image to the element in another td.

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of reasons your fiddle wasn't working.

- You were using JQuery syntax, but you didn't have JQuery selected under Frameworks and Selections
- There were issues with your HTML, tags weren't closed properly
- The javascript you posted only runs once, and that's when the page loads. What it says is effectively "When the page loads, for every single checkbox that is checked, add an image to every link" which is not what you want. You want one image for only the right link, if there are any selected.

I've forked your fiddle, with some updates, including adding JQuery and fixing the html up a bit. It should have the basic functionality you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/GLquL/1/

Namely, here's the relevant HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">
                <div id="lnCont">
                    <div id="Country" class="lnk">Country <span class="shown-image">selected</span></div>
                    <div id="language" class="lnk">language <span class="shown-image">selected</span></div>
                    <div id="food" class="lnk">food</div>
                    <div id="Color" class="lnk">Color</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div id="b_country" class="hidden inputs">
                   <div class="aaa">
                       <input type="checkbox" class="grp" value="USA" name="USA" id="id1" />
                       <label class="lbl " title="USA " data-name="USA " for="id1">USA</label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="aaa">
                       <input type="checkbox" class="grp " value="china" name="china" id="id1 " />
                       <label class="lbl" title="china" data-name="china" for="id1 ">china</label>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden inputs">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Javascript:

```
// Make it so when you click on Country, the appropriate inputs are shown
$("#Country").click(function() {
    $(".inputs").addClass("hidden");
    $("#b_country").removeClass("hidden");
});

// We want this function to run every time a checkbox is checked or unchecked inside #b_country
function checkCountries() {

    if ($("#b_country input:checked").length > 0) {
        // There's at least one checked checkbox!
        $("#Country").addClass("active");
    } else {
        // No checked checkboxes at all. Let's get rid of our image.
        $("#Country").removeClass("active");
    }
}
// Run it now. There may be inputs that are checked by default!
checkCountries();

// Now, run that function each time an input changes its value inside #b_country
$("#b_country input").change(checkCountries);
```

And some CSS:

```
.hidden {display:none;}
.lnk {cursor:pointer;}
.lnk .shown-image {display:none;}
.lnk.active .shown-image {display:inline;}
#lnCont { width:130px;}
```

There are definitely improvements that can be made on this fiddle, but it should more than work for your case, and it will provide you with a starting point.

Comment: My main issue is I cant target a particular element in first td, like b_country, i need to have a generic selection of any input checkboxes or radio buttons on second td should add image to corresponding <td> element on the right, I can target the $("#Country").addClass("active"); I would not know the id there. That is the main issue I have.